# Testing a REST API with GoConvey

Tags: testing, go

I am writing a simple service and was wondering how should I approach testing the REST API Endpoints using GoConvey?

Ideally I believe I would have to launch my server to test it against, but for some reason I am not able to wrap my head around on how to do it with Go.

I am using the vanilla net/http stack for this service and mgo for the database.

Any idea and help would be very welcomed :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [net/http/httptest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/) package is useful for creating a server for a specific http.Handler.

[Andrew Gerrand's testing talk](https://talks.golang.org/2014/testing.slide#12) goes over the httptest.Server and httptest.ResponseRecorder starting slide 12

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out